# How to make a client and server communicate with each other in a user defined network in docker?

Tags: python, docker, http, python-requests

I have a basic client server program written in python which I have containerized using docker. In this program, I want the client to request to the server to display a html file on the client. In one container, I have the client and in another the server. I want these containers to communicate in a user defined docker network and with that have the client communicate with the server  but I am unable to do that. I have already tried with docker run and, by starting in a docker-compose file too. I'll be attaching the codes too.

The commands that I am using for executing is,

Server:

```
docker run --name server -p 9000:9000 --network mynet server:1.0
```

Client:

```
docker run --name client --network mynet client:1.0
```

Here is the code for client.py along with the respective dockerfile

```
import urllib.request
fp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://localhost:9000/")

encodedContent = fp.read()
decodedContent = encodedContent.decode("utf8")

print(decodedContent)

# Close the server connection.
fp.close()
```

Now, the dockerfile

```
 FROM python:alpine3.10
 COPY client.py /client/

 WORKDIR /client/

 CMD python ./client.py
```

Here is the code for server.py along with the respective dockerfile

```
import http.server
import socketserver

handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", 9000), handler) as httpd:
# This instruction will keep the server running, waiting for requests from the client.
      httpd.serve_forever()
```

Now, the dockerfile

```
FROM python:alpine3.10
WORKDIR /server/
EXPOSE 9000
COPY server.py /server/
COPY index.html /server/
CMD python ./server.py
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the actual run commands and/or compose file

Comment: Did it. You can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your client is trying to connect to itself on localhost, not the server container.

Assuming you're using Docker Compose, with a file similar to this

```
version: 3
services:
    client:
       .... 
       depends_on: 
           - server 
    server:
       ...
```

Then the client would need to communicate with `http://server:9000`, so change the code to that, and it should work fine.

If not using Compose, you'll need to provide a hostname and shared network argument to the docker run command

```
$ docker network create mynet
$ docker run --rm --name server --network mynet server:1.0
```

(new terminal)

```
$ docker run --rm --network mynet client:1.0
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Directory listing for /</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Directory listing for /</h1>
<hr>
<ul>
<li><a href="server.py">server.py</a></li>
</ul>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226070/discussion-on-answer-by-onecricketeer-how-to-make-a-client-and-server-communicat).